# are the "come up with" "produce" exchangeable?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I am wondering are the expression "come up with" and "produce" exchangeable?

this is an example from a [post](https://hbr.org/2018/11/how-to-be-creative-when-youre-feeling-stressed).

> To start, you need to let go of trying to “make yourself” come up with
>   something creative

it seems that this sentence can be re-written as

> To start, you need to let go of trying to “make yourself” produce
>   something creative

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this context they mean the same thing, but "produce" is more formal, and "come up with" is casual and relaxed. Use "produce" in legal or academic work.